# HTML Checkboxes in Form POST

Tags: html

vI am working with HTML and have a form with a group of checkboxes:

```
-> What are your favorite colors?
---> Red
---> Green
---> Blue
```

Say I selected, Red AND Green. In the form post, I want it to look like: `"favorite-color": ["red", "green"]`. Now, it only shows one of the colors, even if I select multiple. Here is some sample code:

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="red" name="color" value="red">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="red">Red</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="green" name="color" value="green">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="green">Green</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="blue">Blue</label>
</div>
```

My post, when I select red AND green:

```
{'color': 'green'}
```

By the way, I am using Django as my backend to parse the form POST.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the code ?

Comment: Give your checkbox names `[]` at the end and it will be submitted as an array to the server. `name='favorite-color[]'`

Comment: @imvain2 That's not true at all.

Comment: All the checkboxes will be included in the form data (assuming a regular form submission, you've tagged this [tag:jquery] and [tag:javascript] but there's no sign of any JS (or HTML!) in your "code"). How you get the submitted data to be expressed as an array in your server side code depends on the server side language / framework that you are using.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I meant PHP will process it as an array when posted.

Comment: @imvain2 — The OP didn't say they were using PHP.

Comment: I am using django, will provide an upadte

Comment: That's really not much of an update. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ok will add code right now

Comment: And the server-side code… and the JavaScript…

Comment: I updated my code, as I had previously put in the wrong snippet. There is no JS and no server side code. Just printing request.POST

Comment: There is **no way** that that code, without something else which you haven't shared with us, will produce `{'color': 'green'}`. You haven't even used the word `color` in the code you've shared with us!

Comment: I updated it, sorry! I accidentally put the wrong snippet bfore.

Comment: Given that your question is "what is your favorite color?", not favorite **colors**, this seems like an X/Y problem.

Comment: I meant for it to be checkboxes, I can change the question for clarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [this blog](https://sixfeetup.com/blog/django-form-data-in-post):

> For multiselects or inlines (one-to-many fields) that have multiple values, use .getlist():

So:

```
request.POST.getlist("color")
```

Comment: Thank you! Tested it and it worked. Is there any way to automatically do this in the form POST? Otherwise, I will need to iterate through each key in the form POST, check if it maps to a checkbox question, and then use this code. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've no idea. I haven't used Django for about a decade.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!! Would you mind upvoting since I made my answer better?

Comment: I had a side question: do you know how to make the group required? Meaning that at least one must be selected? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Give all the `input type="checkbox"` elements the same value for their `name` attribute and then the values from the checked checkboxes will be submitted as a single value for the one name. In most server-side environments, that means that if you request that form value, you'll get all the values with the single form field request.

Comment: No. Under normal circumstances, it will be submitted as `favorite-color=red&favorite-color=green`.

Comment: So what are you suggesting that the OP *changes*? Because it sounds like they are doing that already.

Comment: @Quentin I don't get any impression about what the OP is doing.